# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 3, 51, 39, 32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I have two different problems occurs at the same time.

I am having dimensionality problems with MaxPooling2d and having same dimensionality problem with DQNAgent.

The thing is, I can fix them seperately but cannot at the same time.

**First Problem**

I am trying to build a CNN network with several layers. After I build my model, when I try to run it, it gives me an error.

```
!pip install PyOpenGL==3.1.* PyOpenGL-accelerate==3.1.*
!pip install tensorflow gym keras-rl2 gym[atari] keras pyvirtualdisplay 

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation
from keras_visualizer import visualizer 
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

```
env = gym.make('Boxing-v0')
height, width, channels = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n
```

```
input_shape = (3, 210, 160, 3)   ## input_shape = (batch_size, height, width, channels)
```

```
def build_model(height, width, channels, actions):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Convolution2D(32, (8,8), strides=(4,4), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape, data_format="channels_last"))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last"))
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, (4,4), strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last"))
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu"))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(actions, activation="linear"))
  return model
```

```
model = build_model(height, width, channels, actions)
```

It gives below error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling2d_12" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 3, 51, 39, 32)

**Second Problem**

My `input_shape` is `(3, 210, 160, 3)`. I am using the first 3 on purpose due to I have to specify the `batch_size` before. If I do not specify it before and pass it as `(210, 160, 3)` to the `build_model` function, below `build_agent` function gives me an another error:

```
def build_agent(model, actions):
  policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr="eps", value_max=1., value_min=.1, value_test=.2, nb_steps=10000)
  memory = SequentialMemory(limit=1000, window_length=3)
  dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy,
                 enable_dueling_network=True, dueling_type="avg",
                 nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=1000)
  return dqn
```

```
dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-4))

dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=10000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_11_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 3, 210, 160, 3)

Deleting batch size number in the model construction phase, removes the MaxPooling2D incompatibility error but throws DQNAgent dimensionality error. Adding the batch size to the model construction phase removes DQNAgent dimensionality error but throws the MaxPooling2D incompatibility error.

I am really stucked.

Comment: Adding a random dimension at the beginning is not specifying a batch size, the input shape is always specified without the batch/samples dimension.

Comment: You should probably be asking about the DQNAgent dimension error instead of what you tried to solve it.

Comment: If I don't add that integer at the beginning, ```dqn.fit``` error says conv2d got 5 dimension array while I gave it 3 dimension. Note that I don't add random integer to the input shape in this scenario, which means while I am defining 3 dimensions in the model, keras automatically adds batch size to the expected array. But, it is giving me an error that says the model received 5 dimension array which is not expected.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy yes but actually I am okay with solving one of it. I have two problems occuring at the same time.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that error and the code that produces it in detail, including imports and everything.

Comment: Do you know why your model is getting input with shape  (1, 3, 210, 160, 3)?

Comment: I have no clue where the first two integers came from.

Comment: I think that is the actual problem you need to solve, maybe the environment is generating unexpected data.

Comment: I am checking the environment shape and it give me as below 
```>> input_shape = env.observation_space.shape
>> print(input_shape)
>> #Output: (210, 160, 3)```

Comment: In your "second problem", the input shape is not the same as in the first problem right? Did you try using DQNAgent with the default parameters, like not setting enable dueling network?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I found where (1, 3, 210, 160, 3) came from. The first integer is the batch size automatically created. It is 1 due to I didn't specify any number. The second digit is the ```window_length=3``` which is in the dqnagent constructor. Even if I give 1 or 0 to window_length, it is not removed from the input array. If I remove it from the parameters, it gives me an error.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried creating the agent with default parameters as you suggested. Still giving me the same error.

Comment: Ah yes that is because DQN uses a sequence of images, and that is not a problem with Atari since the images are one channel, but you have a problem as your images are color, you need to rethink this or use 3D convolutions (which can have its own problems). Do you see that you actually have one problem and not two?

Comment: I would also be grateful for help with the MaxPooling2D input size issue.

Comment: That is not an actual problem, you have 3D images basically, which cannot be processed by any 2D layer, that is why I suggested to use 3D convolutions (with 3D max pooling).

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with input_shape. input_shape=input_shape[1:]

Working sample code

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

input_shape = (3, 210, 160, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (8,8), strides=(4,4), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape[1:], data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (4,4), strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="linear"))

model.summary()
```

Output

```
Model: "sequential_7"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 51, 39, 32)        6176      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling  (None, 25, 19, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 22, 16, 64)        32832     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling  (None, 11, 8, 64)        0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_11 (Conv2D)          (None, 9, 6, 64)          36928     
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 3456)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 512)               1769984   
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 256)               131328    
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 514       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,977,762
Trainable params: 1,977,762
Non-trainable params: 0
```